# Mysql Query from Two table

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to join Two queries of mysql in a query ??

Like:

```
select * from a + select * from b
```

So that I can use them in a single php loop.

Comment: What are the structures of these tables? and how they are related?

Comment: Do values exist for each table for all rows?  If so, SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM a INNER JOIN a.id=b.a_id

Answer (score 3):

If they have the same number of columns and the datatypes are the same in each column, then you can use a `UNION` or `UNION ALL`:

```
select * 
from a 
UNION ALL
select * 
from b
```

If you provide more details about the tables, data, etc, then there might be another way of returning this data.

A `UNION` will return only the `DISTINCT` values, while a `UNION ALL` selects all values.

If this is the route that you need to take, and you still need to identify which table the data came from, then you can always create a column to identify which table the data is from , similar to this:

```
select *, 'a' TableName
from a 
UNION ALL
select *, 'b' TableName
from b
```

This allows you to distinguish what table the data came from.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier creating sql "variables" like:

```
select varA, varb from TableA, tableB;
```

and you can just play with values in PHP accessing properties.

That way you can take conditions in the query like:

```
select varA, varb from TableA, tableB where varA.id = varB.foreingId bla bla...
```

;)